# Fancybox wiht ui-datepicker not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, fancybox

i want to include datepicker-ui in fancybox but the datepicker not showing in modal.
I change z-index to be bigger on datepicker-ui.

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
                <label style="color:#003580;">Дата на настаняване:</label>
                <input type="text" id="modal-datepicker1" readonly/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label style="color:#003580;">Дата на напускане:</label>
                <input type="text" id="modal-datepicker2" readonly/>
```

This is html in modal he is whit display:none;

```
 $('#btnForm').click(function () {
        $.fancybox({
            autoScale: true,
            content: $("#divForm").html(),
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            afterLoad: function () {
                $("#modal-datepicker1").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                });
                $("#modal-datepicker2").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                });
                             }

        });

    });
```

Datepickers are there in DOM tree, but they not showing.
What can i do? Please, any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check your console for any alerts or errors. Please check that the jQuery UI is being loaded properly.

Comment: Also, why are they both `readonly`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forked the CodePen from @Janis as it did not work exactly.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vmRRGL

**HTML**

```
<p>Date: <br />
  <input type="text" id="modal-datepicker1" />
</p>
<p>Date readonly: <br /> 
  <input type="text" id="modal-datepicker1" readonly />
</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#btnForm").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open({
      src: "#divForm",
      type: "inline",
      touch: false,
      autoFocus: false,
      afterLoad: function() {
        $("#divForm input").datepicker({
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Since `input` has `readonly` attribute, if a user selects a date, it canot be written into the field. I would advise not using `readonly`. If you want to prevent the user from entering content except via the datepicker, there is a way to do that too.

Comment: Hi,
 I commented all of my code and put your decision, but still not working. The datepicker are there but still not showing. Showing only icon for it. I don't have any errors in the console

Comment: Interesting, what icon are you seeing? Datepicker UI does not show icon by default and I do not see in your code that you would add an icon. Maybe you have multiple datepickers scripts on your page?

Comment: Yes i have more two datepickers in my project. They work perfectly. The icon is shown when have class hasdatepicker.When the datepicker is initialized in page. Maybe thear is the problem. When I want to loadед datepicker in fancybox . I will check it out for multiple datepickers .

Comment: I really have multiDatesPicker: version: "1.6.3" . What  search  to do there.

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick demo and it works fine without `readonly` attribute -

```
  <p>Date: <br />
    <input type="text" id="modal-datepicker1" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Date readonly: <br /> 
    <input type="text" id="modal-datepicker1" readonly />
  </p>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmdYvg

Comment: Yes i see but in my project not work maybe something.
Something hinders. Some API or  style  maybe, i don't know .Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was find something and want to show you.

```
  <div class="col-md-6">
            <label style="color:#003580;">Дата на настаняване:</label><br>
            <input type="date" id="modal-datepicker-date-from" style="border: 1px solid #ddd;" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label style="color:#003580;">Дата на напускане:</label><br>
            <input type="date" id="modal-datepicker-date-to" style="border: 1px solid #ddd;" >
        </div>









  $("a.fancybox").click(function() {
        $.fancybox({
            autoScale: true,
            content: $("#divForm").html()
        });

           $('#modal-datepicker-date-from').on('click',function(){
               if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
               $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
                   dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                   setDate: new Date(),
               });

           }
           });


    });
```

Simply and good. Simply and good. I hope so this will  help for someone.